# How to search media library alt text and title fields

Tags: search, media

I need to be able to search in the WordPress media library alt text and title fields.

I've previously used a plugin called Media search Enhanced by 1fixdotio (https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-search-enhanced/) but this is no longer functioning.

How can I search in all fields in the media library (backend is the priority)? I have thousands of images with useful alt text, which are often needed to be searched when drafting new posts.

I'm happy to use a plugin or to add some lines to functions.php if required.